# Inherited WinForm UserControl doesnt show embedded controls

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, abstract

Have an abstract user control with a text box and base coloring set to white background.  When I attempt to inherit it to another class, the components are not shown and coloring does not take affect.

The Base userControl:

```
namespace xBox
{
#if DEBUG
public partial class NgoUserControl : UserControl
{
#else
    public abstract partial class NgoUserControl : UserControl
{
#endif
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // NgoUserControl
        // 
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window;
        this.Name = "NgoUserControl";
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(631, 117);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }
  }
}
```

The Inherited control:

```
namespace xBox
{
public partial class CheckBox : NgoUserControl
{
    public CheckBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

}
}
```

In the example above the base color and size are ignored. Also if I add any controls to the base usercontrol they are missing..  Oddly if I abstract a winform the same way, it works with no problems/omissions..  Very confusing/frustrating..  any help is appreciated... Rob

Comment: Does `NgoUserControl ` have a constructor that calls its `InitializeComponent` method that you neglected to show us?  If not, add one.

Comment: I wouldn't name your class "CheckBox" since there already is one in the standard library.  It makes things confusing.

Comment: Well that was silly..  The constructor was missing the Initialize Component..  Thanks TnTinMn!!!